# How to use a join rather than two sub queries

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I have these two queries that were originally a subquery that I would like to do on a join but I am not sure how to do this properly.

My smaller example table looks like this

```
SupplierId|CompanyName|Country
```

These fields are mandatory so they can all be joined on. My original subquery looks like this

```
select *
from Suppliers
where CompanyName != 'Nord-Ost-Fisch Handelsgesellschaft mbH'and Country = 
(Select country 
from Suppliers 
where CompanyName = 'Nord-Ost-Fisch Handelsgesellschaft mbH');
```

The first part of my query is finding a country that belongs to a company name and returns Germay

```
Select Country
From Suppliers 
Where CompanyName = 'Nord-Ost-Fisch Handelsgesellschaft mbH'
```

The second part of my query finds all suppliers that correlate to the above query. `Where Country = 'Germany'` should not be hardcoded in.

```
Select *
From Suppliers
Where Country = 'Germany' -- this based on above statement
 and CompanyName != 'Nord-Ost-Fisch Handelsgesellschaft mbH'
```

The query I am trying looks like this

```
 Select *
 From Suppliers s join Suppliers ss
 on s.SupplierID = ss.SupplierID
 Where ...
```

I am just failing to see how if I joined these two tables, how I can still get the country of Germany and then query against that result.

Comment: Can you list both table fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there's no inherent reason why you can't keep it a subquery in this case; I actually think it makes the intent slightly more obvious.

But if you want a self-join instead, here is how it would look (I used `s` for the table that will return the actual supplier info, and `c` for the table that is simply filtering by country):

```
select s.*
from Suppliers s
inner join Suppliers c
    ON s.Country = c.Country
WHERE c.CompanyName = 'Nord-Ost-Fisch Handelsgesellschaft mbH'
AND s.CompanyName <> 'Nord-Ost-Fisch Handelsgesellschaft mbH'
```

Just be specific about which table field you are filtering on.

Or, if you like, you could put the filter on c as part of the join:

```
select s.*
from Suppliers s
inner join Suppliers c
    ON s.Country = c.Country
    AND c.CompanyName = 'Nord-Ost-Fisch Handelsgesellschaft mbH'
WHERE s.CompanyName <> 'Nord-Ost-Fisch Handelsgesellschaft mbH'
```

Comment: Thank you for both. I never thought of using the same column in two tables against each other by doing an = and <>

Comment: Easiest way to think of it is just to pretend that you are joining two entirely different tables, then make sure that every field (in the join, in the WHERE, in the SELECT) is explicitly from one table or the other.